# How to run jest test inside other test block?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

For example I have 2 test, how can I test one depend on another one?
Sometimes, we want to have some E2E test, which could reproduce same test steps.

What I think right now is using separate function for testing, but if there is a quick way to run other test with one statement which would be great.

```
test('test1', () => {
})
test('test2', () => {
  // run test1 here
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I understand from your comment on another answer is: You want to share part of a test just for some specific tests.

To do this you can use the `beforeEach` and `beforeAll` functions inside a `describe` block.

See my example:

```
describe('some module', () => {
  it('should test something awesome', () => {
    // My test 1
  })

  it('should test something awesome', () => {
    // My test 2
  })

  describe('something specific or tests that are related to each other', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // code that runs for each tests within this describe block
    })

    it('should test something awesome', () => {
      // My test 3
    })

    it('should test something awesome', () => {
      // My test 4
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question very well.

What I understood was that you have some steps that we need to write to all tests right?

I think that you can use the `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` function to not repeat this code. But is always good that your test to transmit everything that do you need to create the senary.

Tests should work as a document as well!

Comment: beforeEach will run before all test, but I just want to have same steps inside several tests, not all tests.